# Why Laravel 5.8 makes repeated queries to the database when working with the session

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

In Laravel 5.8, when working with a session, two extra queries to the database are performed compared to Laravel 5.7.

**Laravel 5.7**

[image]

```
select * from `sessions` where `id` = '00kaQxJLG6roUAp9DaCui7esa31sbthHqEzwW62H' limit 1
```

**Laravel 5.8**

[image]

```
select * from `sessions` where `id` = 'anFc8QgnSpMbMVHcuxAldxKdLhNyo3IUNavylQTD' limit 1

update `sessions` set `payload` = 'YTozOntzOjY6Il90b2tlbiI7czo0MDoiQm12QlFHNzVNRVpZcTRkMWZwcmNMS2kwcm12czlvZkpXZUg0cFpEQyI7czo5OiJfcHJldmlvdXMiO2E6MTp7czozOiJ1cmwiO3M6MTY6Imh0dHA6Ly9kZXYubG9jYWwiO31zOjY6Il9mbGFzaCI7YToyOntzOjM6Im9sZCI7YTowOnt9czozOiJuZXciO2E6MDp7fX19', `last_activity` = 1559161593, `user_id` = '', `ip_address` = '127.0.0.1', `user_agent` = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/73.0.3683.86 Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36' where `id` = 'anFc8QgnSpMbMVHcuxAldxKdLhNyo3IUNavylQTD'

select * from `sessions` where `id` = 'anFc8QgnSpMbMVHcuxAldxKdLhNyo3IUNavylQTD' limit 1
```

New installation. No packages.

Comment: Are both installs using the database as the session driver, or is one using the file driver for sessions?

Comment: Yes. Database in 5.7 and database in 5.8

Answer (score 3):

Working on a Laravel 8 app and I also encountered this scenario, **fortunately it was nothing to worry about** as explained here:

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/duplicate-session-query

Output from laravel debugbar

```
select * from `sessions` where `id` = 'ZGtPxAAAlFsMcZOC4OXnwRRX8n8gf9uWsqeefjoP' limit 1
update `sessions` set `payload` = `sdffbbblablablverylong`
select * from `sessions` where `id` = 'ZGtPxAAAlFsMcZOC4OXnwRRX8n8gf9uWsqeefjoP' limit 1
```

> It means that in your app use database driver for session and you use it to store some informations. No, it's not a problem. Don't worry.
>
> -MichalOravec

Answer (score 1):

**Resolved**

In Laravel 5.8 middleware was changed

```
Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php
```

In method handle was added

```
$this->saveSession($request);
```

if the session has been configured it updated in the database.

In Laravel 5.7 only in cookies.

Comment: I'm experiencing this issue on an app I have. What did you actually do to stop the duplicate query from running?

Answer (score -1):

You have written the same query twice.

```
select * from `sessions` where `id` = 'anFc8QgnSpMbMVHcuxAldxKdLhNyo3IUNavylQTD' limit 1
```

You can solve this by initializing this query to a variable and then using the variable whenever you need to.

```
$session = select * from `sessions` where `id` = 'anFc8QgnSpMbMVHcuxAldxKdLhNyo3IUNavylQTD' limit 1;
```

This should remove the duplicates.

The query in eloquent

```
$session = Session::query()->where('id','anFc8QgnSpMbMVHcuxAldxKdLhNyo3IUNavylQTD')->take(1)->get();
```

Comment: You misunderstood that this is happening in the framework itself, not code the user added.